# Where do I find the hidden Toast?

Tags: payday-2

According to one of the devs from Payday there's supposed to be some sort of Hidden Toast.

https://twitter.com/ZombeyPaz/status/596381527631597569

What is the Hidden Toast, and where do I find it? Is it like Almir's Toast from the White X-Mas heist?

Comment: [This](https://youtu.be/D2GSOoO8Edo?t=1m24s) is what you're looking for. I do not know if it is in that spot all the time.

Comment: @Unionhawk Write that as an answer so it can be marked as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the white xmas heist, it is a random loot in the presents with a super low drop chance.

Buuuut it also appears on the Shoutout raid (the shadow raid's loud counterpart in the murkywater warehouse)

I'm not certain where it is exactly, but it is supposed to be outside the main playing area, near where the trains are at the end of the heist.

Answer (score -2):

It's from the whitechristmas update so you can find it only in that heist, (maybe becouse sometimes it spawns in other heists like meltdown)
[McBadass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iGB2Bp1fVWM) found it, and may you go to check all the gifts that are in the map, becouse it's rare, and maybe there isn't the toast.
And maybe in meltdown it's [here](https://youtu.be/D2GSOoO8Edo)